# Same code, different running times

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, web-services

I have two applications with one common method and the same code, the first application is a website compiled in 32 bits and the second one is wcf service compiled in 64 bits.

Both machines are 64 bits:
Ram 6 gb
Processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU  E5645 @2.40 GHZ

The problem is that the same piece of code takes more time when running in the WCF service:

```
    Private Shared Sub AddImageToOutputPDF(ByRef pdfDoc As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument, ByVal freeImg As FreeImgDLL.freeImage)
    Dim page As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage = pdfDoc.AddPage
    Dim gfx As PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
    Dim ts As New TimeSpan
    Dim st As New DateTime
    Dim en As New DateTime

    st = DateTime.Now
    If freeImg.verticleDPI = 0 Then
        freeImg.EstimateAndSetResolution()
    End If


    Dim tiffImage As PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage = PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromFreeImage(freeImg)

    page.Width = New PdfSharp.Drawing.XUnit((tiffImage.Width / tiffImage.HorizontalResolution) * 72)
    page.Height = New PdfSharp.Drawing.XUnit((tiffImage.Height / tiffImage.VerticalResolution) * 72)


    gfx.DrawImage(tiffImage, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height)

    en = DateTime.Now

    ts = en - st

    _log.Debug("Page Operation--- Add Page To Pdf using PdfSharp. ------------------Time in seconds: " + ts.TotalSeconds.ToString)

End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you calling the method just once, or many times?

Comment: What kind of a discrepancy are we talking about? Minutes? Seconds? Do you get the same discrepancy if you compile your WCF service as 32-bit? What about if you run the code in isolation - but tested in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions? Are they both compiled as release or is one in debug mode?

Comment: I'm calling the method once. The difference in time to process 9 pages is: WCF Service  Time in seconds: 7.2460288   and Website App Time in seconds: 3.4061

Comment: What is calling the website app 9 times?  What is calling the WCF service 9 times?

Comment: First, make sure you're doing your timings with a Release build and no debugger attached. Second, I would recommend creating a simple test application that isolates the code in question. Compile and test in 32 bit, then compile and test in 64 bit. That's the only way to know if the difference has to do with 32/64, or if it's due to something about Web/WCF.

Comment: Have you hooked a profiler up to any of these processes? You have access to your code; take the initiative and profile it!

Comment: Daniel and Jim, I'll will do what you both suggested and comeback later with the results. BTW even though the logs says Debug, both codes are been compare in release mode.